# Alert Dialog still open even after I left the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

In the `Profile Page` I have a function `openGallery` and it uses `ImagePicker` to choose how users want to select images or videos whether by camera or gallery. So in this function I am returning an `AlertDialog` to show the options of taking pictures and videos by camera or choosing from the gallery. The function looks something like this :

```
void openGallery() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        ),
        content: SizedBox(
          height: 260.0,
          width: 360.0,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () async {
                  final image = await getMedia(ImageSource.gallery);

                  setState(() {
                    files = image;
                  });
                },
                title: Text(
                  'Choose a photo from gallery',
                  style: GoogleFonts.mada(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    letterSpacing: 1.1,
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: const IconButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  icon: Icon(
                    MdiIcons.memory,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                onTap: () async {
                  final image = await getMedia(ImageSource.camera);

                  setState(() {
                    files = image;
                  });
                },
                title: Text(
                  'Capture a photo',
                  style: GoogleFonts.mada(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    letterSpacing: 1.1,
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: const IconButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.camera,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I click on the `add` icon this `openGallery` function is called and that is what I want. After choosing a file instead of navigation to a screen where a user can add a caption it does both. After choosing a file the `dialog` is still open even in a different screen. Please help me on how I can stop this from happening after choosing an image. All I want is for it to go to the screen where the user can add a caption. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before the code that goes to another screen, you need to add the following code:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

In onTap at the end Dont forget  to use Navigator.of(context).pop() to close  the dialog

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

See [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `pop()` to close dialog;

```
onTap: () async {
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
   final image = await getMedia(ImageSource.gallery);
   setState(() {
      files = image;
   });
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final image = await getMedia(ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
files = image;
Navigator.pop(context);//to close dialog after chose an image
Navigator.push(context, route);//for going to your rout
});
```

you should to use **Navigator.pop(context);** to close dialog because the it use **context**

and it should be used **after any dialog** to close it

see the documentation [AlertDialog class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks I tried that but I kinda used it outside ``` setState ``` so thank you again

Comment: @kaoma_khomotjo
The most important thing is the idea
good luck

Comment: @Nagual no not the same its replace  current page to another

Comment: @StephenOstermiller man im new here and try to help 
and I help him  then I have -1 thanks

Comment: exactly, it replace page so one line instead of two lines pop() push()

Comment: be careful  if you want to back to previous page using POP  cant because there is no route